# Add field not in schema with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to add a new field to a document, but this isn't working:

Creating my UserModel prototype:

```
model = require("../models/user")
UserModel.prototype.findOneAndUpdate = function(query, params, cb) {
    model.findOneAndUpdate(query, params, { returnNewDocument: true, new: true }, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            cb(false, data);
        } else {
            cb(err, false);
        }
    });
};
```

Then calling it

```
userFunc = require("../../model_functions/user")

userFunc.findOneAndUpdate({
    "email.value": userEmail
}, {
    $set: {"wat":"tf"}
},
function (err, updatedUser) {
    //This logs the updated user just fine, but the new field is missing
        console.log(updatedUser);
                  ...
});
```

This successfully updates any field as long as it exists, but it won't add any new one.

Comment: that new field have been added in schema?

Comment: Is `wat` defined within the schema for users? Mongoose is designed to enforce the schema, including discarding properties that don't align to it.

Comment: No, but that shouldn't be necessary to add it, or at least that's what I thought. It is meant to be a temporary field.

Comment: Also, if I do it directly in the mongo console, it works, it adds the new field.

Comment: @LuisEgan It does matter with Mongoose. The ODM is designed to enforce the schema you've defined, verifying that each property belongs and discarding those that don't. If you want documents to be a blend of schema and schema-less, you can define a property as [`Mixed` type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-mixed-js) that can then contain any variety of information needed. Otherwise, if you don't want the schema enforced like this, then Mongoose probably isn't right for your use case.

Comment: Oh so it's not possible having a temporary field using mongoose.. my solution was adding it to the schema but since it's not going to always 
 be used it seemed like unnecessary code. I'll just it to the schema then. Thanks @JonathanLonowski

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can add and remove fields in schema using option `{ strict: false }`

**option: strict**

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to
> our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get
> saved to the db.

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });
```

And also you can do this in update query as well

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  query,  //filter
  update, //data to update
  { //options
    returnNewDocument: true,
    new: true,
    strict: false
  }
)
```

You can check the documentations [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)

Comment: Ok, but I'd like to add that the first did not work for me, just adding it to `findOneAndUpdate()` did.

Comment: It does work if you run the create or insert query... Here main motive is to aware people with option `strict` and the fact that people can add and remove field if the field does not exists in mongoose schema

Comment: For me, the option first i.e. setting the `strict` to `false` worked for insert and update both.

Comment: does the strict option also effect the read operation?

Answer (score 11):

You can add new fields in schema User using  .add

```
require('mongoose').model('User').schema.add({fullName: String});
```

Thanks.-

Comment: It worked for me. I don't need to compromise on Model strictness.

Comment: In this case, how to check if the field exists or not in the schema and then add it if not exists?

Answer (score 1):

use **{strict:false}** when you are creating schema

```js
const testschema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    id: Number,
    isUsed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
},{strict:false})
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [JonathanLonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski)

> The ODM is designed to enforce the schema you've defined, verifying that each property belongs and discarding those that don't.

So in order to update fields using `mongoose` the field must exist in the model's schema.

Comment: It is possible... Use `{ strict: false }` to set or unset the new field in mongoose... Read this https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5378

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Forgot about that. Good call. – [Relevant documentation.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)