# How do I add new keys to a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I recently started developing an app for my senior project which requires me to use some type of database. For that I decided to go with Mongoose since it is noSQL and slightly easier to pick up.

So, fast forward and I run into a problem where I can't figure out how to edit an already existing Schema and add new keys into it.

For example, I have this Schema which represents a post(think Tweets or Facebook posts) that holds:

- A string that holds the body of the post
- The id of the user that created the post
- The Date of when the post was created

My code for that is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const PostsSchema = new Schema({
  Value: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  User: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'users'
  },
  Date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

// Create collection and add schema
mongoose.model('posts', PostsSchema, 'posts');
```

What I want now is to access that schema in some way and add a new key to it using something similar to maybe

```
PostsSchema.add({Private: { default: false}});
```

Meaning that, now the schema in the database will look something like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "1831g98af21n9s5u7s9ccchj5"
    },
    "Value": "Beautiful day outside, can't wait to go jogging!",
    "User": {
        "$oid": "9a79ab143lbk9lk55wq327oi3226m"
    },
    "Date": {
        "$date": "2018-10-29T01:28:44.408Z"
    },
    "Private":  "false"
    "__v": 0
}
```

So back to my question, is there any way to do this? Or if you have a link to documentation of such methods I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you Greatly!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add field not in schema with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934800/add-field-not-in-schema-with-mongoose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the field to the schema with a `default`:

```
const PostsSchema = new Schema({
  Value: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  User: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'users'
  },
  Date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  Private: {type: Boolean, default: 'false'}
});
```

Since you have a `default` any new record will have it as well as any new **instance** of an old model saved before you added the `private` field.

If you really need more `dynamic` approach the usual recommendation is using [Mixed Type](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) with all the pluses and minuses that come with it.

Comment: I'm aware of what you recommended but I wanted to do it dynamically, if I can call it that. To explain better, imagine an app that allows users to create their own human. By default we might give the human keys like arms, legs, head, etc. Now you might want to allow the user to add different characteristics to the Schema like torso, nose, and so on. This is a very basic example but it is essentially the functionality that I want to access so I can edit an already existing schema.

Comment: Not something that is by design or recommended as a best practice. More here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1867

Comment: What would be a good alternative to my initial approach rather modifying the initial Schema?

Comment: The usual recommendation as I updated the answer is simply using Mixed type. That way you can add anything you want. It is flexible but you have to deal with change tracking etc.