# Is it possible to update a document (insert a new field) after a query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to make a query (mongodb + node.js) based on the user email and after that I want to insert a new field. So far, I have tried to use user.save(), but from what I can see this can only update the value of the pre-existing field(s) within the found document. Please help me out.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate(value) {
        if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
            throw new Error('Email is invalid')
        }
    }
}
    }})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {  

user.xxx=some_variable

user.save()

})
```

Comment: Use `{ strict: false }`. Possible duplicate of [Add field not in schema with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934800/add-field-not-in-schema-with-mongoose)

Comment: Also user.save() returns a promise so you need to handle this.  user.save().then((err, doc) => ...