# Trouble updating Mongoose model, .findByIdAndUpdate() not working

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm trying to update an item in a mongoDB, but I can't get it to work properly. I've googled the question and I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. I don't get any errors in the console, it actually says the update was successful. So far I've been able to create and find items in the DB just fine..Here's my code if anyone can help me spot the problem I'd really appreciate it!

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/fruits", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

// CREATE
// Fruit.create({
//     name: "Grape",
//     rating: "7"
// }, (err, fruit) => {
//     if (err) {
//         console.log(err);
//     } else {
//         console.log("SAVED FRUIT!");
//         console.log(fruit);
//     }
// });

// READ
// Fruit.findById({ _id: "5f85e2e36ef7e00c97ac484f" }, (err, fruit) => {
//     if (err) {
//         console.log(err);
//     } else {
//         console.log("FOUND FRUIT!");
//         console.log(fruit);
//     }
// });

// UPDATE
Fruit.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: "5f85e2e36ef7e00c97ac484f" }, { $set: { color: "Green" } }, (err, fruit) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("UPDATED FRUIT!");
        console.log(fruit);
    }
});
```

Here's what the DB looks like,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f85e2e36ef7e00c97ac484f"),
    "name" : "Kiwi",
    "rating" : 6,
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f85e3003dbb9d0c9bcca90d"),
    "name" : "Grape",
    "rating" : 7,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define color in mongoose schema

```
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    color: String   // add this one.
});
```

Also while updating, no need to use $set, just pass the object.

```
Fruit.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: "5f85e2e36ef7e00c97ac484f" },  { color: "Green" }, (err, fruit) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("UPDATED FRUIT!");
        console.log(fruit);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you know why I can't update it with a new key:value? (for ex. color : "Green")

Comment: Check out this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934800/add-field-not-in-schema-with-mongoose

Comment: EXACTLY, what I was looking for! This solved my issue, thanks a lot!!