# mongoose didn't update changed document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is schema

```
  const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      userId: Number,
      wallet: Number,
      owningStock: Object,
      firstPrice: Object,
      owningItem: Object,
  })
```

and I tried to add a new pair of key&value in the docs.

```
User.findOne({userId : userId})
.then(user => {
       if(user.votedTimestamp == undefined){
            user.votedTimestamp = 0;
            user.save()
       }
}
```

But it didn't update the document.
It's still

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("618bbbe0134b06050305f057"),
  userId: 000,
  wallet: 000,
  owningStock: {

  },
  firstPrice: {

  },
  __v: 0
}
```

How can I save the added key-value in the document?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the field "votedTimestamp" in the schema.
Add `strict: false`  in the schema. You can refer to the link
[Add field not in schema with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934800/add-field-not-in-schema-with-mongoose)