# push value of one schema into another schema

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a file ./models/Image.js

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const imageSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    description: {type: String},
    author:{type:String},
    filename: {type: String},
    path: {type: String},
    originalname: {type: String},
    mimetype: {type: String},
    size: { type: Number},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    authorname:{type:String}
});
module.exports = model('Image', imageSchema);
```

I have another file ./models/User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
  name :{type:String,required : true} ,
  email :{type  : String,required : true} ,
  password :{type  : String,required : true} ,
  date :{type : Date,default : Date.now}
});

const User= mongoose.model('User',UserSchema); 
                                            
module.exports = User;
```

and a function inside routes/user

```
router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.title = req.body.title;
    image.description = req.body.description;
    image.filename = req.file.filename;
    image.path = '/img/uploads/' + req.file.filename;
    image.originalname = req.file.originalname;
    image.mimetype = req.file.mimetype;
    image.size = req.file.size;
    //image.authoremail= User.req.email; // what should i do here
    
    await image.save();
    res.redirect('/user/feed');
});
```

What i want is to put users name and email inside image schema so that i can compare it for later purposes
for example in a page of dashboard user is only shown the picture he/she has uploaded but inside page 'feed' pictures of all users is displayed with there respective name

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should add user name and email field in the image schema. then set required = false, if it's not required for every case or you can add it without custom the schema by set strict = false in schema. it allow you to save or update the document in your case.

this is the answer that show how to set strict = false
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50935227/15072782

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image Schema by using,reference document concept. So that you can just store user id.

```
const imageSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    description: {type: String},
    author:{type:String},
    filename: {type: String},
    path: {type: String},
    originalname: {type: String},
    mimetype: {type: String},
    size: { type: Number},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    authorname: {                                      // update here
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User' 
    }
});
module.exports = model('Image', imageSchema);


const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
  name :{type:String,required : true} ,
  email :{type  : String,required : true} ,
  password :{type  : String,required : true} ,
  date :{type : Date,default : Date.now}
});

const User= mongoose.model('User',UserSchema); 
                                            
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: can you also tell me what to do here where it the code is commented 
```
router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.title = req.body.title;
    image.description = req.body.description;
    image.filename = req.file.filename;
    image.path = '/img/uploads/' + req.file.filename;
    image.originalname = req.file.originalname;
    image.mimetype = req.file.mimetype;
    image.size = req.file.size;
    //image.authoremail= User.req.email; // what should i do here
    
    await image.save();
    res.redirect('/user/feed');
});
```

Comment: from post body itself, you can send the user id and inplace of `authername = req.body.authername`

Comment: i replaced the comment with this 
image.authorname=req.body.authorname;
i checked on the db user id is not being saved, db shows all information but nothing about authorname is there
i guess I am not understanding something here

Comment: can you show me the post body?

Comment: do you mean the ejs file? or the post function
the function is mentioned above?

Comment: req.body should be  `{
  title = "Some title",
  description = "Some description",
  filename = "some file name",
  path = '/img/uploads/',
  originalname = 'Some originalname',
  mimetype = 'some mimetype'
  size = 'some size',
  auther = '92d0bcf6-5a69-11ec-bf63-0242ac130002' //User table ID
}`

Comment: {
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2021-12-11T09:52:39.860Z"
    },
    "title": "application 3",
    "description": "this is app",
    "filename": "b0f9aab8-b6d5-4ecb-add7-32d4bf2c37ec.jpg",
    "path": "/img/uploads/b0f9aab8-b6d5-4ecb-add7-32d4bf2c37ec.jpg",
    "originalname": "app3.jpg",
    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
    "size": 120994,
    "__v": 0
}
this is the req.body which is shown on the mongodb, as you can see no authorname

Comment: You should make changes to image schema as i updated and in ejs when you send data you should choose a user and send ID.

Comment: do you have email? i can mail you everything

Comment: shashikaml54@gmail.com

Comment: check your email